# Посев данных Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel

При попытке посева данных ловлю вот такие ошибки. В чем может быть дело?[image: Seeder]

Comment: Проблема в том, что у Вас установлена привередливая версия MySQL (5.7). Она требует, чтобы поля, у которых нету значений при вносе - имели стандартные знаения + Allowed Null.

Comment: MySQL 5.5 используеться

Comment: Но похоже Вы правы: при инсерте оно тоже ругаеться что не установлены значения полей по умолчанию, которые не заполняються. Если заполнять все поля, тогда работает. Как отключить эту проверку, чтоб оно всегда заполняло, а которые не заполняються, оставались пустыми?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте, я приведу Вам пример, который исключит данные ошибки:

```
Schema::table('users', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->string('email');
    $table->string('date_of_birth')
        ->nullable()
        ->default(null);
});
```

Создавая миграции такого типа, с аттрибутами `nullable` и `default(null)`, Вы, будучи выполняя данные миграции и сидеры, добьетесь успешного заполнения первичных  данных.

Comment: Работает. Спасибо. Сударь Вы - гений!